# Update logic for data integration

Tags: python, sql-server, updates, auto-update

I really need help in finding logic for my script for updating :(

I have a SQL Server database with customer data with `ModifiedDate` column. And I am moving this data to Odoo using External API with exactly the same columns.

My script will run every day and take the new data from the SQL Server database and add it to Odoo; it has to update those customers which have changed also.

For creating, I am taking `max(CreateDate)` and using it in the query to take customers after it.

But I am not able to find a good solution for update. Any help?

PS: as data is pretty big, I need to find the fastest solution :( Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution.

I will do one time fetch to the data. And then take today as a parameter and use in the query as:

```
where ModifiedDate > today
```

If anybody has a better idea, please share :) Thanks :)